# Undefined class error in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction

If i have two class in different headers:

first header:

```
include "second_header.h"
class A
{
   int x;

};
```

and the second:

```
include "first_header.h"
class A;
class B
{
   A a;
};
```

why does the compiler gives me an error of undefined class,can i have an explanation ?

Answer (score 4):

Because in the `second_header.h` the class `A` haven't actually been *defined*, only *declared*. And to use a non-reference/non-pointer of a class it needs to be fully defined.

As you don't need the `second_header.h` file in `first_header.h`, simply remove that include from the `first_header.h` file.

Answer (score 3):

You're asking the compiler to recursively include the headers. You don't need to include the second header in the first header, try removing that include.

As a rule you should always use [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in your C++ headers by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use *forward declaration* of A if you actually use an object of class A.
You should remove the `class A;` line from the second header, or
You can use pointers in the class B :

```
class A; // forward declaration, no need to include A's header.
class B
{
   A* a; // don't create an A object (compiler would need A's header) but an A pointer.
};
```